# How can I call a javascript function from ionic ts?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a javascript function named "gimmick" which is inside index.html. And I have a typescript function. My criteria is to call the javascript function from inside of the typescript function. Some one please suggest  some idea so that I can access the javascript function from typescript.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it:

1. in your *index.html* file :

   ```
   <button id="callMyJSFunction" onclick="myJSFunction()" style="display:none;"></button> <script> function myJSFunction(){ alert('IN'); } </script>
   ```
2. in your *ts* file:

   ```
   myTSFunction(){ var btn = document.getElementById('callMyJSFunction'); btn.onclick.apply(btn); }
   ```